# How to refresh html canvas directives in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a page that when the plus button is clicked the tallyboxes should increment one line as well as the votes. For example when I have a 51 votes the tallyboxes should display 10 boxes and 1 line. In my webpage adding votes is working fine the 51 votes increment to 52 but the tally boxes doesn't increment. I put a $watch and $observe to it but it doesn't fixed. What I've done so far is:

```js
var tb = angular.module("tb", []);
tb.controller("tallyboxController", function ($scope) {
 'use strict';
    $scope.addVote = function(no){
    $scope.presidents.votes+=1;
    console.log($scope.presidents.votes);
    }

    
    $scope.addLine = function(){
     //alert("Tina");
     $scope.hello = "tina";
     console.log($scope.hello);
     };

        $scope.label = {
      table:{
        cName:"Candidate's Name",
        cVote:'Vote',
        cTB:'Tally Boxes',
        cNV:'No of votes',
        period:'.'
      },
    };
    
    $scope.presidents = [
      {
        no:'1',
        name:'Jeoanna Lingh',
        votes:51,
      }
    ];
    
    $scope.candidates = [
      $scope.presidents,
      $scope.vicepresidents
    ];

    console.log($scope.presidents.votes);


     

});


var tb = angular.module('tb');

tb.directive('drawing', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element,attrs){
      var votes = scope.value.votes;
      var ctx = element[0].getContext('2d');
      var remainder = 0;
      var oneBox = 0;

        if(votes > 4){
          if(remainder = votes%5){
            oneBox =  (votes-remainder)/5 ; 
          }
          drawOneBox()
          }else{
          remainder = votes;
        }

        console.log(votes);

        ctx.beginPath()

        function drawOneBox(){
          var i;
            for (i=0;i<oneBox;i++){
              ctx.moveTo(5+i*25, 5);
              ctx.lineTo(25+i*25, 5);

              ctx.moveTo(5+i*25, 5);
              ctx.lineTo(5+i*25, 25);

              ctx.moveTo(25+i*25, 5);
              ctx.lineTo(25+i*25, 25);

              ctx.moveTo(5+i*25, 5);
              ctx.lineTo(25+i*25, 25);

              ctx.moveTo(25+i*25, 25);
              ctx.lineTo(5+i*25, 25);
              ctx.strokeStyle = "Red";
              ctx.stroke();
            }
         
              if(remainder==1){
                ctx.moveTo(5+i*25, 5);
                ctx.lineTo(5+i*25, 25);
                ctx.strokeStyle = "Red";
                ctx.stroke();
              }

              if(remainder==2){
                ctx.moveTo(5+i*25, 5);
                ctx.lineTo(25+i*25, 5);

                ctx.moveTo(5+i*25, 5);
                ctx.lineTo(5+i*25, 25);
                ctx.strokeStyle = "Red";
                ctx.stroke();
              }

              if(remainder==3){
                ctx.moveTo(5+i*25, 5);
                ctx.lineTo(25+i*25, 5);

                ctx.moveTo(5+i*25, 5);
                ctx.lineTo(5+i*25, 25);

                ctx.moveTo(25+i*25, 5);
                ctx.lineTo(25+i*25, 25);

                ctx.strokeStyle = "Red";
                ctx.stroke();
              }

              if(remainder==4){
                ctx.moveTo(5+i*25, 5);
                ctx.lineTo(25+i*25, 5);

                ctx.moveTo(5+i*25, 5);
                ctx.lineTo(5+i*25, 25);

                ctx.moveTo(25+i*25, 5);
                ctx.lineTo(25+i*25, 25);

                ctx.moveTo(25+i*25, 25);
                ctx.lineTo(5+i*25, 25);

                ctx.strokeStyle = "Red";
                ctx.stroke();
              }          
           };             
        } // end 
      };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="tb">
<head lang="en">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Tally Boxes</title>
</head>
<body data-ng-controller="tallyboxController" data-ng-init="init()">
  <div id="container">
   </div>
  <div class="container-table">
    <table border="1" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>{{label.table.cName}}</td>
                <td colspan="2">{{label.table.cVote}}</td>
                <td>{{label.table.cTB}}</td>
                <td>{{label.table.cNV}}</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in candidates[0]">
                <td>{{value.no}} {{label.table.period}} {{value.name}}</td>
              <td><button ng-click="addVote(key)">+</button></td>
              <td><button ng-click="minus(key)">-</button></td>
              
                <td><canvas width="500" height="26" id="{{value.no}}" drawing></canvas></td>
                <td>{{value.votes}}</td>           
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
</div>

  <script src="angular.min.js"></script>  
  <script src="tallyboxController.js"></script>
  <script src="tallyboxDirective.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you make it work in the snippet? Quite a few things seem broken.

Comment: Hello. There are still wrong in my codes so I am asking here. I do my best to run it my out of luck It doesn't work fine. :-) Would you help me please

Comment: Sure. I meant the part you said is working (51 increasing to 52), but it's not.

Comment: Yeah I try to do that here but were using a web socket in that part of code. And I need nodejs server to run it. Hmm the most important to me right now is when the user click the add button the tally boxes should increment one line. . Don't mind the votes I can fix that later when I figured out my problem in html canvas directives. :-)

Comment: Alright, let's deal with the canvas part. What needs to happen with the boxes when you hit increase or decrease? Each box represents 5 votes?

Comment: yes you are right each box represents 5 votes. So when I hit increase the boxes should increase one line and when I hit decrease the boxes should decrease one line. I stock for this for 3 weeks, I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needed a couple of crucial fixes, here's what I did:

- added an attribute `candidate` and an isolate scope to the directive so we have double-binding between the isolate scope variable with the controller scope variable (so that we don't have to fetch it using `scope.$parent...`)
- moved the liner code into a function so it can be called again when needed (linker gets executed only once)
- added a `votes` watcher, which will rerender the canvas using the function I mentioned in the previous step.
- added a clean canvas call at the beginning of rendering (otherwise it would draw over the same canvas over and over again)
- added the missing `oneBox = votes / 5;` in case there is no remainder
- added the decrease vote functionality (not crucial for fixing, of course, but easier for testing)

Here is the working version:

```js
var tb = angular.module("tb", []);
tb.controller("tallyboxController", function($scope) {
  'use strict';
  $scope.addVote = function(no) {
    $scope.presidents[no].votes += 1;
  }
  
  $scope.minus = function(no) {
    $scope.presidents[no].votes -= 1;
  }


  $scope.addLine = function() {
    //alert("Tina");
    $scope.hello = "tina";
    console.log($scope.hello);
  };

  $scope.label = {
    table: {
      cName: "Candidate's Name",
      cVote: 'Vote',
      cTB: 'Tally Boxes',
      cNV: 'No of votes',
      period: '.'
    },
  };

  $scope.presidents = [{
    no: '1',
    name: 'Jeoanna Lingh',
    votes: 52,
  }];

  $scope.candidates = [
    $scope.presidents,
    $scope.vicepresidents
  ];

});


var tb = angular.module('tb');

tb.directive('drawing', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      candidate: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        var colors = ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Yellow'];

        scope.$watch("candidate.votes", function(newValue, oldValue) {
          console.log('rendering', newValue);
          render();
        });

        function render() {
          var votes = scope.candidate.votes;
          var ctx = element[0].getContext('2d');
          var remainder = 0;
          var oneBox = 0;
          
          // clear canvas (needed for subtracting votes)
          // and is a good practice anyway
          element[0].width = element[0].width;

          if (votes > 4) {
            if (remainder = votes % 5) {
              oneBox = (votes - remainder) / 5;
            }
            else {
              oneBox = votes / 5;
            }
          } else {
            remainder = votes;
          }
          
          drawOneBox();          

          function drawOneBox() {
            ;
            for (var i = 0; i < oneBox; i++) {
              
              var color = colors[Math.floor(i/5)];

              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.moveTo(5 + i * 25, 5);
              ctx.lineTo(25 + i * 25, 5);

              ctx.moveTo(5 + i * 25, 5);
              ctx.lineTo(5 + i * 25, 25);

              ctx.moveTo(25 + i * 25, 5);
              ctx.lineTo(25 + i * 25, 25);

              ctx.moveTo(5 + i * 25, 5);
              ctx.lineTo(25 + i * 25, 25);

              ctx.moveTo(25 + i * 25, 25);
              ctx.lineTo(5 + i * 25, 25);
              ctx.strokeStyle = color;
              ctx.stroke();
            }
            
            // recheck the color
            color = colors[Math.floor(oneBox/5)];

            if (remainder == 1) {
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.moveTo(5 + i * 25, 5);
              ctx.lineTo(5 + i * 25, 25);
              ctx.strokeStyle = color;
              ctx.stroke();
            }

            if (remainder == 2) {
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.moveTo(5 + i * 25, 5);
              ctx.lineTo(25 + i * 25, 5);

              ctx.moveTo(5 + i * 25, 5);
              ctx.lineTo(5 + i * 25, 25);
              ctx.strokeStyle = color;
              ctx.stroke();
            }

            if (remainder == 3) {
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.moveTo(5 + i * 25, 5);
              ctx.lineTo(25 + i * 25, 5);

              ctx.moveTo(5 + i * 25, 5);
              ctx.lineTo(5 + i * 25, 25);

              ctx.moveTo(25 + i * 25, 5);
              ctx.lineTo(25 + i * 25, 25);

              ctx.strokeStyle = color;
              ctx.stroke();
            }

            if (remainder == 4) {
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.moveTo(5 + i * 25, 5);
              ctx.lineTo(25 + i * 25, 5);

              ctx.moveTo(5 + i * 25, 5);
              ctx.lineTo(5 + i * 25, 25);

              ctx.moveTo(25 + i * 25, 5);
              ctx.lineTo(25 + i * 25, 25);

              ctx.moveTo(25 + i * 25, 25);
              ctx.lineTo(5 + i * 25, 25);

              ctx.strokeStyle = color;
              ctx.stroke();
            }
          };
        }
        render();
      } // end 
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="tb">

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tally Boxes</title>
</head>

<body data-ng-controller="tallyboxController" data-ng-init="init()">
  <div id="container">
  </div>
  <div class="container-table">
    <table border="1" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>{{label.table.cName}}</td>
          <td colspan="2">{{label.table.cVote}}</td>
          <td>{{label.table.cTB}}</td>
          <td>{{label.table.cNV}}</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in candidates[0]">
          <td>{{value.no}} {{label.table.period}} {{value.name}}</td>
          <td>
            <button ng-click="addVote(key)">+</button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button ng-click="minus(key)">-</button>
          </td>

          <td>
            <canvas width="500" height="26" id="{{value.no}}" candidate="value" drawing></canvas>
          </td>
          <td>{{value.votes}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh thanks God. That's what I need, I've been doing that for almost 3 weeks and your amazing. Thank you a lot for fixing it and for giving me notes on how you do it. .I'm gonna study your codes. Thanks Thanks Thanks :-)

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad I could help, keep up the good work! :)

Comment: May I ask another question. . What if I want to change every 5 color of tally boxes. For example, the first five is color red, then the following five would be green and so forth. . Should I use loopings or if not, what should I need to do? Thanks sir

Comment: Yeah, looping is fine, you should probably set the color inside a variable and then change it on every 5th iteration. Need me to show you the code?

Comment: Is it okay to show me some example of codes.? The truth is this is my first time to used angular so I am not yet familiar in some complicated part. :-) Thanks again in advance

Comment: You're welcome! :) Alright, the key here is to call `beginPath()` every time you need a new color (think of it like changing a pencil) to prevent color spilling (having **everything** drawn in the last color selected). I hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you again Sir. That is what I wanted right now. . And thank you so much for your great explanation. I can learn a lot with you. :-*

Comment: Sir can you help me in this too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27896723/insert-data-into-table-with-complicated-td-cells I used the calendar table I've searched earlier but I do not know how to do it.